# Sexual deprivation vs sexual frustration

Tags: sexuality

Recently I came across a "sexual deprivation" term and started to google what it means. Weirdly each time I was trying to put it as search term the Google redirected me to the "sexual frustration" concept, which I do not treat as correct replacement. You can [try it yourself](https://www.google.com/search?q=sexual+deprivation&oq=sexual+deprivation&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqBggAEEUYOzIGCAAQRRg7MgYIARBFGDsyBggCEEUYPDIGCAMQRRg8MgYIBBBFGD3SAQg1OTkzajBqMagCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), it should behave the same for you. Neither Google has a right and knowledge to define medical conditions, nor me, so I am asking the medical community for a competent answer to this.

**Are sexual deprivation and sexual frustration the same medical conditions?**

From what I found out they are not. Both terms have numerous often contradictory definitions, this is what I concluded in layman's terms:

> **sexual deprivation** - insufficiency or deficiency or absence of sexual life and desire that is caused counsciously or by disorder

> **sexual frustration** - dissatisfaction by own sexual life and inability to fulfill and reach your sexual desires

As for me these are two totally different medical states, so I have no idea why Google redirects one to the other.

My questions regarding the matter:

1. Are they the same medical states or different from the viewpoint of conventional medicine?
2. Are they abnormalities/disorders or just lifestyle choice? Or maybe [lifestyle diseases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifestyle_disease)?
3. I didn't find any definition of both in authoritative medical sources, such as [DSM-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSM-5) or ICD, only Wiki [sexual frustration article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_frustration), which is not sufficient for me. 
   Is F52.0 ICD disagnosis [Hypoactive sexual desire disorder](https://www.aapc.com/codes/icd-10-codes/F52.0#:%7E:text=ICD%2D10%20code%20F52.,Mental%2C%20Behavioral%20and%20Neurodevelopmental%20disorders%20.) the same as *sexual deprivation*?
   Though I found several mentions of sexual frustration [in DSM-5](https://repository.poltekkes-kaltim.ac.id/657/1/Diagnostic%20and%20statistical%20manual%20of%20mental%20disorders%20_%20DSM-5%20(%20PDFDrive.com%20).pdf), but only in the section of subjective distress in several disorders, such as Frotteuristic Disorder, Sexual Masochism Disorder, Pedophilic Disorder, etc.
4. Are they useful for diagnosis and triage?

Sorry for such many questions asked, but they are important to outline my struggles to understand the concept. I suppose my question is on-topic here. but it more fits to [Psychology.SE

Comment: Ì would think that sexual deprivation would be one of the things at lead to sexual frustration.  e.g. sexual deprivation is a subset of causes for sexual frustration

Comment: ok, but does sexual frustration constitute a mental disorder or it's just a distress?